# Regarding Employee Record in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working in an employee program in python and I an facing difficulties

The out put should look like below

```
from array import *
arr = array("i", [])
n= (int(input("Enter the number of employee's: ")))
arr.append(n)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    name = input("Enter the name of the employee %s: " %(i))

    from array import *
    salary = array("f", [])
    x = int(input("Enter %s current salary: " %(name)))
    arr.append(x)

    from array import *
    Q1 = array("f", [])
    rating1 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q1: " %(name)))
    arr.append(rating1)

    from array import *

    Q2 = array("f", [])
    rating2= int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q2: " %(name)))
    arr.append(rating2)

    from array import *

    Q3 = array("f", [])
    rating3 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q3: " %(name)))
    arr.append(rating3)

    from array import *
    Q4 = array("f", [])
    rating4 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q4: " %(name)))
    arr.append(rating4)

def totalrating():
    totalrating = [rating1, rating2, rating3, rating4]
    total = sum(totalrating)
    return(total)

def overallrating():
    overallrating = totalrating()/4
    return(overallrating)

def display():
     print(name, x, rating1, rating2, rating3, rating4, totalrating(), overallrating())

display()
```

[image]

My programs goes like

The Out put is only returning the second value not the first can you help me what needs to be done

[image]

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: First: Why do you import array over and over again.
Second: What is the point of the loop if you don't call display until the loop is over and you overwrite the values each iteration of the loop
There's more I can see to optimize/fix this, but these are the two major glaring ones right now

Comment: So if I rewrite the code without array

Comment: n= (int(input("Enter the number of employee's: ")))
 for i in range(1,n+1):
        name = input("Enter the name of the employee %s: " %(i))
        salary = int(input("Enter %s current salary: " %(name)))
        rating1 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q1: " %(name)))
        rating2= int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q2: " %(name)))
        rating3 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q3: " %(name)))
        rating4 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q4: " %(name)))
How can I print two values

Answer (score 0):

Alright so there is a lot of cleanup to do here. I will point out the changes in code comments and try to further explain as needed.

```
# The multiple import of array are redundant and the way you are using this is actually
# wrong so it's not needed. So I am commenting out this one and then deleting the rest.
# from array import *

# Here you just need a basic list and not an instance of the array module.
# arr = array("i", []) <- old code for reference.
arr = []

n= (int(input("Enter the number of employee's: ")))

# I commented out this line because you don't ever access this element after you set it
# so you can just not set it at all.
# arr.append(n)

# Because we got rid of the append above we can loop from 0 to n instead of 1 to n+1
for i in range(0, n):
    name = input("Enter the name of the employee %s: " %(i))

    # These sub arrays is unnecessary and part of the problem
    # salary = array("f", [])
    salary = int(input("Enter %s current salary: " %(name)))

    # So the way you are appending stuff is part of the problem.
    # Let's remove all of these appends out and we can do them at the end of the loop
    # arr.append(x) 

    rating1 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q1: " %(name)))
    rating2 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q2: " %(name)))
    rating3 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q3: " %(name)))
    rating4 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q4: " %(name)))

    # Here we can append a dictionary to the array with the data laid out how you want it.
    arr.append({
        'name': name,
        'salary': salary,
        'rating1': rating1,
        'rating2': rating2,
        'rating3': rating3,
        'rating4': rating4,
    })

# Note the display function is now passing in the employee info here.
def totalrating(employee):
    # So this function can be modified a few ways
    # Also don't name variables the same as functions. It can lead to name clashing issues.
    '''
    # This is the original code and I am leaving is for posterity.
    totalrating = [rating1, rating2, rating3, rating4]
    total = sum(totalrating)
    return(total)
    '''

    '''
    # Here is the first way it could be modified.
    total_rating = [
                   employee['rating1'], employee['rating2'], employee['rating3'],
                   employee['rating4']
                  ]
    total = sum(total_rating)
    return total
    # not there is no need to put () around the return in python
    '''

    # Here is how I would modify it though.
    rating_keys = ['rating1', 'rating2', 'rating3', 'rating4']
    return sum([employee[rate] for rate in rating_keys])

# This can be rewritten in one line and since it's only used in one place it should be done there
# def overallrating():
#     overallrating = totalrating()/4
#     return(overallrating)

def display():
    # Now that the array has been cleaned up we can go through the array and print it.
    for employee in arr:
        # Instead of calculating them in the print statement just make variables ahead of time
        total = totalrating(employee)
        # This whole function is a one liner that should just be done here.
        overall_rating = total/4
        print(
            employee['name'], employee['salary'], employee['rating1'], employee['rating2'],
            employee['rating3'], employee['rating4'], total, overall_rating
        )

display()
```

This should output as you asked. Cleaned up without the comments and old code the final product is:

```
arr = []
n= (int(input("Enter the number of employee's: ")))

for i in range(0, n):
    name = input("Enter the name of the employee %s: " %(i))
    salary = int(input("Enter %s current salary: " %(name)))
    rating1 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q1: " %(name)))
    rating2 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q2: " %(name)))
    rating3 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q3: " %(name)))
    rating4 = int(input("Enter the rating %s received for Q4: " %(name)))

    arr.append({
        'name': name,
        'salary': salary,
        'rating1': rating1,
        'rating2': rating2,
        'rating3': rating3,
        'rating4': rating4,
    })

def totalrating(employee):
    rating_keys = ['rating1', 'rating2', 'rating3', 'rating4']
    return sum([employee[rate] for rate in rating_keys])

def display():
    for employee in arr:
        total = totalrating(employee)
        overall_rating = total/4

        print(
            employee['name'], employee['salary'], employee['rating1'], employee['rating2'],
            employee['rating3'], employee['rating4'], total, overall_rating
        )

display()
```